# Finding the sum of Digits expressed as a string of Letters

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have a string `str` of lowercase letters in the range `[a-z]`.
Few letters of the string when combined together, represent a digit from `[0-9]` i.e. "zero" = 0, "one" = 1, "two" = 2 and so on.

The characters in the string are jumbled. However, it is guaranteed that all the characters in the string can be used to form a set of digits. Some digits can be repeated as well. There are no invalid characters such as `a`, `p`, `q` etc.

My task is to find the sum of the digits represented by `str` .

Examples :
`str` = "oneeno" should output `2 (1+1)`
`str` = "onewtofoursevne" should output `14 (1+2+4+7)`

let `solve(s)` represent solving for a particular sub-string of `str` .
i have an array of strings, `v` to store the spellings of the digits. v = {"zero", "one", "two", ... "nine"};

I will break down `s` and add the digit value, wherever I am able to find a set of characters representing a digit.

```
if (contains(s, v[i]) == true)
    dp[s-v[i]] = i + solve(s-v[i])
```

`s-v[i]` represents the set of characters in `v[i]` removed from `s` . As it is not possible to subtract strings in that manner, I substitute `s-v[i]` with `change(s, v[i])` (in my code).

This seems like a recursive function with multiple repeating sub-states.
For example : `solve(s - v[1] - v[4] - v[7]) = solve(s - v[4] - v[1] - v[7])` .

I've used Top-Down Dynamic Programming for this where `dp[s-v[i]]` is the state of `s` when characters representing `v[i]`  are removed from it. Instead of removing characters, I simply replace the used characters with a `$` symbol. If the entire string has the `$` character, it means we've found a valid solution (which forms the base case).

As the strings are jumbled, I use a map of strings to store the sub-states and the strings are always sorted to prevent any redundancy.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using ll =  long long;

vector<string> v = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
map<string, int> dp;
bool b;

bool check(string str, int n) {
    string t = v[n];
    sort(t.begin(), t.end()); sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    while(i < t.size() && j < str.size()) {
        if(t[i] == str[j]) {
            ++i; ++j; ++k;
        }
        else ++j;
    }
    
    return (k == t.size()) ? true : false;   
}

string change(string str, int n) {
    string t = v[n];
    sort(t.begin(), t.end());
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    
    int i=0, j=0;
    while(i < t.size() && j < str.size()) {
        if(t[i] == str[j]) {
            str[j] = '$';
            ++i; ++j;
        }
        else ++j;
    }
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    return str;
}

int solve(string str, map<string, int>& dp) {
    
    if(str[str.size()-1] == '$') {
        b = true; // a solution exists
        return 0;
    }

    if(dp.find(str) != dp.end()) // if state is already computed
        return dp[str];
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(check(str, i)) {
            return dp[change(str, i)] = i + solve(change(str, i), dp);
        }
    }
    
    return dp[str] = 0;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
    
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input", "r", stdin);
        freopen("output", "w", stdout);
    #endif
    
    string str; cin >> str;
    sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    
    b = false; 
    
    int res = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(check(str, i)) {
            dp[change(str, i)] = i + solve(change(str, i), dp);
        }
        if(b) { // valid solution found
            res = dp[change(str, i)];
            break; 
        }
    }
    
    cout << res;    
    return 0;
}
```

The code works alright for smaller strings :
Example : `str = "towsnveefourfive"` yields `18 (2 + 7 + 4 + 5)`
However, for larger strings such as `str = "towsnveefourfiveone"` yields `0` instead of `19`

What could be the error in my approach ?

Comment: Is something like `otnwoe` a possible input, where the letters have been fully permuted? Or are the letters for each number guaranteed to be contiguous?

Comment: Yes, it is possible for the letters to be fully permuted

Comment: Yes! Although the question is framed differently, the approach required is identical.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest and fastest way to solve this problem is to write equations that relate the number of occurrences of certain letters to the number of occurrences of certain digits.  Then you can count the occurrences of those letters and solve for the occurrences of digits by Gaussian elimination.

You have 10 digits to solve for, so you need 10 independent equations.  We'll start with the easy ones:

```
X = 6s
Z = 0s
W = 2s
G = 8s
```

'six' is the only digit that has an x, so the number of xs equals the number of 6s.  Similarly for 'zero' and zs, and the others here.

Then some more complex ones:

```
O = 1s + 2s + 4s
H = 3s + 8s
F = 4s + 5s
V = 5s + 7s
S = 6s + 7s
I = 5s + 6s + 8s + 9s
```

Solving, we get:

```
0s = Z
1s = O - W - F + V - S + X
2s = W
3s = H - G
4s = F - V + S - X
5s = V - S + X
6s = X
7s = S - X
8s = G
9s = I - G - X - V + S - X
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what was `s`

Comment: Heh, right.  I didn't want to write, e.g., 4 = ...something that might not be 4...

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version of Matt's approach:

```
0 = z
1 = o - z - w - u
2 = w
3 = h - g
4 = u
5 = f - u
6 = x
7 = s - x
8 = g
9 = i - f + u - x - g
```